Does Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 2 4 10 collapse the hierarchy of different kinds of scriptures?
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html
Verse 2.4.10:

स यथार्द्रएधाग्नेरभ्याहितात्पृथग्धूमा विनिश्चरन्ति, एवं वा अरेऽस्य महतो भूतस्य निह्̣स्वसितमेतद्यदृग्वेदो यजुर्वेदह्̣ सामवेदोऽथर्वाङ्गिरस इतिहासह्̣ पुराणम् विद्या उपनिस्̣अदह्̣ श्लोकाह्̣ सूत्रान्यनुव्याख्यानानि व्याख्यानानि; अस्यैवैतानि निःश्वसितानि ॥ १० ॥


sa yathārdraedhāgnerabhyāhitātpṛthagdhūmā viniścaranti, evaṃ vā are'sya mahato bhūtasya niḥsvasitametadyadṛgvedo yajurvedaḥ sāmavedo'tharvāṅgirasa itihāsaḥ purāṇam vidyā upaniṣadaḥ ślokāḥ sūtrānyanuvyākhyānāni vyākhyānāni; asyaivaitāni niḥśvasitāni || 10 ||



As from a fire kindled with wet faggot diverse kinds of smoke issue, even so, my dear, the Ṛg-Veda, Yajur-Veda, Sāma-Veda, Atharvāṅgirasa, history, mythology, arts, Upaniṣads, verses, aphorisms, elucidations and explanations are (like) the breath of this infinite Reality. They are like the breath of this (Supreme Self).


All classes of scripture like Vedas and Puranas seem to be on equal footing - they are all the breath of the Supreme self.
This translation says "mythology" for Puranas.
But there is also a tradition that Shruti takes precedence over scriptures like Puranas in case there is a contradiction.

Brahma Sutras say sruti takes precedence, as the verse you quote says  - it is the breath of God. Puranas are smriti, from men. When I read the the referenced verse, I think you are misinterpreting the translator's intent with his reference to mythology.
